# how do i show selected value in option using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am trying to show a value from database to show in select option

running in PHP,JSON,AJAX,JQUERY

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function () {
    var shop_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/update_shop",
        method: "POST",
        data: {shop_id: shop_id},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        $('#emp_name').value = data[0].emp_id;
            console.log(data[0].emp_id);
            $('#shop_name').val(data[0].shop_name);
            $('#shop_owner').val(data[0].shop_owner);
            $('#shop_phone').val(data[0].shop_phone);
            $('#shop_dist').val(data[0].shop_district);
            $('#shop_loc').val(data[0].shop_location);
            $('#shop_code').val(data[0].shop_code);
            $('#shop_id').val(data[0].shop_id);
            $('#latitude').val(data[0].latitude);
            $('#longitude').val(data[0].longitude);
            $('#create_button').text("Update");
            $('#createOrder').modal('show');
          }
    });
});
```

i expect the out put comes like show data[0].emp_id as selected and show other option in dropdown

Comment: Please show us the output of `console.log(data);` or we will have no clue what's going on. If you think the PHP code is the issue, you need to show that as well. All we know about your application is what you tell/show us.

Comment: Change it to: `$('#emp_name').val(data[0].emp_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question is

> how do i show selected value in option using jquery

and I can't comment as my reputation is below 50.

your answer should be `$('#idOfSelectTag').val('3')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#txtValue').change(function(){
    changeValue($(this).val());
  });
});

function changeValue(){ 
  var value = $('#txtValue').val();
  value =   value==''?  1:  value;
  $('#selTest').val(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selTest">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" id="txtValue" />
<br />
<button onclick="changeValue(4)">Change Value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also using php without jquery.

```
<select class="custom-select col-12"  id="lcount" name="lcount" data-validation="required" >                                            
        <option value="0" <?php if($sdata['lcount']=='0') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>select</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if($sdata['lcount']=='1') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($sdata['lcount']=='2') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($sdata['lcount']=='3') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($sdata['lcount']=='4') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>4</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($sdata['lcount']=='5') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>5</option>
</select>
```